# Text inside the output have interchanges position

Tags: pdf, printing

I printed a pdf file using epson when you view it in PC is ok, when printing the letter are interchange like eg
SUM OF INVOICE 20,000 changes to (printed output hardcopy) MUS FO ECIOVNI 000,002. If i print another pdf document the output is OK, can the invoice pdf have some issue. What could be the problem and what is the solution[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCC6w.jpg)

Comment: What app do you use to print it?

Comment: https://answers.acrobatusers.com/mirror-image-pdf-file-q240067.aspx

Comment: I used foxit pdf reader and the printer was epson.